# Why it c pointer doesn't work here?

Tags: c, malloc

I am beginner to C language and a thing that I can't understand very well is the use of malloc. So I decide to create this example. I would like to understand why it doesn't print out the buffer data and what is the best practice to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* malloc, free, rand */

void f(char * buffer, int i) {
  buffer = (char *) malloc(i+1);
  if (buffer==NULL) 
    exit (1);

  for (int n=0; n<i; n++)
    buffer[n]=rand()%26+'a';

  buffer[i]='\0';
}

int main ()
{
  char * buffer;
  f(buffer, 5);
  printf ("Random string: %s\n",buffer);
  free (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it print "Random string: "?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `buffer = (char *) malloc(i+1);` has no effect outside the function. In effect the function is changing its own copy of `buffer`, and the caller (`main`) never sees this change. This is all very well explained in a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).

Instead of passing it as a parameter, you could return the buffer, since the function doesn't return anything at the moment:

```
char *f(int i)
    /* ... */
    return buffer;

/* ... */

char * buffer = f(5);
```

---

- In C casting `malloc` is a unnecessary, and often considered a
  dubious practice
- The `n` and `i` variable names are somewhat misleading: one expects them the other way around
- `f` is not a goot name for a function

Comment: My doubt is, if I create a pointer inside a function scope, returning it, it will remain valid outside the function? I mean, at the end of the function, the pointer doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: @Leandro You're right to worry. But think of it this way: the pointer itself doesn't exist anymore, that's for sure. But just before it got destroyed, it managed to convey its contents, in effect an address. So now someone else (`buffer` from `main`) holds that address. **So it's safe**, `f` can safely kill all its local variables.

Answer (score 2):

In order to modify pointer passed to the function, you have to use pointer to pointer:

```
void f(char** buffer, int i) {
  *buffer = malloc(i+1);
  if (*buffer==NULL) 
    exit (1);

  for (int n=0; n<i; n++)
    (*buffer)[n]=rand()%26+'a';

  (*buffer)[i]='\0';
}
```

Usage:

```
char* buff;

f(&buff, len);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention how to pass the buffer to the function.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'd like to know also if this is the best practice for this type of problem...

Comment: in the case where I'm trying to change the value of a int, like f(int i), is it the same? f(int ** i)?

Answer (score 1):

Variables are **passed by value** to functions.

When you call `f(buffer, 5)`, then it does not pass the variable `buffer` to function `f`; it only copies the value of the variable `buffer`. In function `f`, a new variable named `buffer` (the parameter variable) is created. When you change the value of that variable, the original variable that you passed in from `main` is not affected.

Different ways to solve this:

Make `f` return the pointer, and save it in `buffer` in `main`:

```
char * f(int i) {
    char * buffer = malloc(i + 1);

    /* ... */

    return buffer;
}

int main() {
    char * buffer = f(5);

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

Or pass a pointer to a pointer to `f`; in `main`, pass the address of `buffer`:

```
void f(char ** buffer, int i) {
    *buffer = malloc(i + 1);

    /* ... */
}

int main() {
    char * buffer;
    f(&buffer, 5);

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the original value of variables that were *passed-by-value*.

If you want to malloc in a function, and return the result of malloc in a variable, then that variable must be *passed-by-reference*.

E.g. instead of:

```
void f(char * buffer, int i);
```

It should be:

```
void f(char **buffer, int i);
```

Answer (score 0):

CNICUTAR is right, but here are interesting information :

MALLOC :

Don't cast malloc (here is an interesting topic about it : [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).

FOR LOOP :

For the for loop you should use this way (C89 version) :

```
int i;
for (i = 0; ...)
```

Regards,